# Javascript pause within function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delay

In the example below I want to pause the script after changing the style of element one. Then after 500 miliseconds, proceed to change the style of element two. As `setTimeout()` requires a function parameter, how do I achieve this without delaying the entire function?

Note: the function is called by `onclick="myFunction()"` on an HTML element.

```
function myFunction() {

    // Declare some variables
    var elementOne = document.getElementById("classElementOne");
    var elementTwo = document.getElementById("classElementTwo");

    // Execute for element 1
    elementOne.style.cssText = "some styles";

    // Wait 500 miliseconds

    // Execute for element 2
    elementTwo.style.cssText = "some styles";
}
```

Comment: Why would settimeout delay the entire function?

Comment: What do you mean by "*without delaying the entire function*"? Can you show us how you would have used `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As `setTimeout()` requires a function parameter, how do I achieve this
> without delaying the entire function?

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_settimeout.asp) and pass a function which changes the style for element 2.

It doesn't delay your the entire function. (In your example `myFunction`). Instead it just delays the execution of the anonymous function which you pass in as a parameter.

```
function myFunction() {

    // Declare some variables
    var elementOne = document.getElementById("classElementOne");
    var elementTwo = document.getElementById("classElementTwo");

    // Execute for element 1
    elementOne.style.cssText = "some styles";

    // Wait 500 miliseconds
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     // Execute for element 2
     elementTwo.style.cssText = "some styles"; 
     }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would just put the Code you want delayed inside an anonymous function like so:

```
function myFunction() {

    // Declare some variables
    var elementOne = document.getElementById("classElementOne");
    var elementTwo = document.getElementById("classElementTwo");

    // Execute for element 1
    elementOne.style.cssText = "some styles";

    // Wait 500 miliseconds

    // Execute for element 2
    setTimteout(() => {
        elementTwo.style.cssText = "some styles";
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: The style change should be in the `setTimeout`, not the variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {

    // Declare some variables
    var elementOne = document.getElementById("classElementOne");
    var elementTwo = document.getElementById("classElementTwo");

   // Execute for element 1
   elementOne.style.cssText = "some styles";

   // Wait 500 miliseconds

   // Execute for element 2
   setTimteout(() => {
     elementTwo.style.cssText = "some styles";
   }, 500);  
}
```